# Can I simplify Hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

For some reasons, I'd like to use different value generated sequences rather than one for all tables, like:

```
@Entity
public class User {
       @Id
       @TableGenerator(name = "user", table = "hibernate_sequences", pkColumnName = "sequence_name",
           valueColumnName = "next_val", pkColumnValue = "user", allocationSize = 1)
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "user")
       private Integer id;
}
```

When my application has more tables(now is more than 50), I want to simplify this code like:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @MyTableGenerator(name = "user")
    private Integer id;
}
```

Is there some way to do this?
In this case, I want to accomplish two goals. First is set some default values to annotation (hibernate annotation, not my custom annotation). Second is use one of my custom annotation represent multiple hibernate annotation.

I'm sorry if I have not explained my question well, and please point it out.

Comment: Yes you can, juste create an new annotation.

Comment: @Zorglube could u please explain more?  better with some code.  Thanks very much. I'm not familiar with java annotation.

Comment: @Zorglube I have read some blogs or documents, and tried some of them. but none of it works. So I'm sorry if I bother you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_USER")
public class User {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: They are not database related annotations at least RDMS databases. Can you share error that you get?